# NoSuchElementException: No line found.?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java and Computer science in general, I keep getting the same error from this code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Trivedi_Chatbot.main(Trivedi_Chatbot.java:28)
```

Please help me if you can.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;

public class Trivedi_Chatbot
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hi there! My name is Alexa Jr!");
        
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        
        while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("Goodbye"))
        {
            
            if ((input.equalsIgnoreCase("What's up?")) || (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Whats up")))
            {               
                System.out.println ("Roof or sky, depending on if you're in a building.");
            }
            
            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("What's the date?")){
                Date d = new Date();
                System.out.println("Today's date is " + d); 
            }
            input = scan.nextLine();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Goodbye! See you soon!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me, how are you running your program?

Comment: How are you running my program? I am using a chrome browser-based compiler called Sololearn.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run your application in cmd or in ide like eclipse or netbeans 
exemple on cmd :
https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-java-program-from-command-prompt/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a transcript of your program being run in a terminal:

```
$ ls
Trivedi_Chatbot.class
$ java Trivedi_Chatbot
Hi there! My name is Alexa Jr!
whats up
Roof or sky, depending on if you're in a building.
goodbye
Goodbye! See you soon!
$ java Trivedi_Chatbot </dev/null
Hi there! My name is Alexa Jr!
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Trivedi_Chatbot.main(Trivedi_Chatbot.java:13)
```

The exception you get is caused when your program is not reading from a terminal.